# How to get HTML textbox value?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to get values of few textboxes on a website in a C# WinForms app.
It is input type text, set to readonly, but when I try to read it in my app using

```
string price = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("price").GetAttribute("value");
```

it returns an empty string.
When I try to set some other (not readonly) input value using `.SetAttribute("value", "testValue")`, it works just fine.

Anyone could help me with this please?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the value from the text box cannot be retrieved using `GetAttribute`.

You can use the following code to retrieve the value:

```
dynamic elePrice = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("price").DomElement;
string sValue = elePrice.value;
```

If you are not able to use `dynamic` (i.e. .NET 4+) then you must reference the 'Microsoft HTML Object Library' from the COM tab in Visual Studio and use the following:

```
mshtml.IHTMLInputElement elePrice = (mshtml.IHTMLInputElement)webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("price").DomElement;
string sValue = elePrice.value;
```

EDIT:
This has been tested with the following code:

```
webBrowser.Url = new Uri("http://files.jga.so/stackoverflow/input.html");

webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
     var eleNormal = (IHTMLInputElement)webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("normal").DomElement;
     var eleReadOnly = (IHTMLInputElement)webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("readonly").DomElement;
     var eleDisabled = (IHTMLInputElement)webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("disabled").DomElement;

     MessageBox.Show(eleNormal.value);
     MessageBox.Show(eleReadOnly.value);
     MessageBox.Show(eleDisabled.value);
};
```

Comment: Both of these return null in the string :(

Comment: I have added an additional code example to make sure that disable and readonly inputs are picked up by `.value`. They appear to work. Can you give an example of the URL you are trying to read.

Comment: http://brainwallet.org/  trying to read the private key and address (I wrote price here just to make the example more clear, the textboxes are called "sec" and "addr")

Comment: Testing this URL via the browser control I get a number of script errors and the "Private Key" field is not populated. The "Secret Exponent" field is populated (id="hash") and I can read this programmatically. The Web Browser control is an embedded version of Internet Explorer 7 so it is possible their JavaScript does not support this version. Do you need to embed a web browser control, could you use Selenium which can control another browser?

Comment: I can use anything, WebBrowser was just the first thing to come on my mind. If you have any better solution, I will be thankful for any advice ;)

Comment: You can use Selenium to launch and control a web browser. It is typically used for test automation for web applications. There is a C# API available to download here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ with documentation within.

Comment: Thanks @JasonAllen. Ur code worked for me. I have posted my question in the link, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323673/unable-to-set-value-to-textbox-control-programatically-in-webbrowser/41345979#41345979". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to use innertext

```
string price = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("price").InnerText;
```