# Unable to set value to textBox control programatically in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to set a value programatically to a textbox in a web browser but it is throwing the Null exception.

This is the code, I have tried:-

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("field-summary").InnerText = "Something";

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("field-summary").SetAttribute("value", "Something");

I have tried to find the element by using the Quick Watch and it is there, but I am unable to set a value.

Hereby, I have attached the snap of watch too.

[image]

And this is the error, I am getting.

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TimeSheet.exe
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

My question is I am trying to set a value to the innertext and I am not doing any manipulation with the InnerText. But still it is throwing error.

I have tried both InnerText, value too. But still unable.

I have also attached the snap, using the Inspect for reference.

[image]

PS: 
1. All these code set are done in the DocumentCompleted Event of the WebBrowser, but still unable..
2. I have accessed other elements (text) in some other pages and used the InnerText for accessing and setting a value for it. But unable to do with this element.

Could some one throw a light on why it is doing so, so I can able to understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you try to set value for element before the element got load into document, for example in load event of form. You should find the element in `DocumentCompleted` event of `WebBrowser` conrtol.

Comment: @RezaAghaei : Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am doing this in DocumentCompleted Event only.. Is there any other problem associated with this..?

Comment: Maybe yes, for example when your elements are loaded using an ajax request or created on the fly using a client-side framework like angular.

Comment: If you share the URL which you trying to use, then the problem can be reproduces, otherwise the question is not useful for other users.

Comment: Hi @RezaAghaei: I am using my organization site with credentials.. so little bit difficult... May I know, Is there any other options to solve this null error?

Comment: No I have no other idea than what I said in previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

May be your elements have not loaded yet.
Do this action in window load event handler.
You can use Jquery events.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution for my problem from SO,.

[How to get HTML textbox value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091944/how-to-get-html-textbox-value)

So, the following code worked for me.

dynamic elePrice = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("price").DomElement;
string sValue = elePrice.value;

Thanks.