# How to get the value from html value Attribute from webbrowser in c#?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I wan to get the value string from "input" element from value Attribute in webbrowser in c#

```
textBox7.Text = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMainctl09_ctl00_CurrentPage").GetAttribute("value");
```

```html
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$$ctl09$ctl00$CurrentPage" type="text" value="5" maxlength="8" size="3" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMainctl09_ctl00_CurrentPage" tabindex="1" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;padding:1px;">
```

[Please See this Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rslAw.jpg)

I want the number --> 5  that between value="This number what I want to get it to textbox7" in html code what I attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
webBrowser.Url = new Uri("http://files.jga.so/stackoverflow/input.html");

webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
     var eleNormal = (IHTMLInputElement)webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("normal").DomElement;
};
```

Reference: [How to get HTML textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091944/how-to-get-html-textbox-value)